# Apache Flink: CsvReader TAB field delimiter

Tags: apache-flink

I am working with a large **CSV** file which uses **TAB** to separate the fields in one row. The problem is that there are more than one **TAB** characters between some fields. I don't want to replace characters because there are about a million lines in the file. I tried the code bellow but it doesn't work, it apparently doesn't find the delimiter and gives me nothing as an output.
If i use **\t** as the delimiter I get an output, but the multiple **TAB** characters are a problem.

```
DataSet<Tuple7<String, String, String, String, String, String, String>> ds = env
            .readCsvFile("../csvResources/1.CSV")
            .fieldDelimiter("\t+")
            .ignoreInvalidLines()
            .types(String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class)
            .project(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Recommend you overcome your reluctance, and clean up the file using something like tr, sed, or awk. I would try using tr -s "\t" which should replace all occurrences of multiples tabs with a single tab.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I thought it would be a really inefficient process, but I tried it and actually finished pretty fast. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported by Flink's built-in `CsvInputFormat`. It will interpret each tab as a field delimiter and assume that some fields are empty.

There are two ways to address this issue.

1. Implement your own input format (possibly forking `CsvInputFormat`). You basically need to change the logic that is responsible for splitting a record into individual fields. Instead of parsing the next field when you observe a field delimiter (tab), you need to check if the next character is a field delimiter as well.
2. Read file linewise (using `TextInputFormat`) and parse each line is a subsequent `MapFunction`.

I'd recommend to go with the second approach. It's easier to implement and maintain.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out for me. I am a total beginner with Flink, so can you get a little bit more specific about the implementation of my own CsvInputFormat?

Comment: I've added a few more details. As mentioned in the answer, I'd recommend the second approach of parsing the records in a `MapFunction`